# Server to auto reset mysql table values at a specific time

Tags: mysql

How do I get the server to reset values in a table column.

For example I have a table called "users" with a column called "rebuy". The rebuy column contains "yes" or "no" values for each users. I want the server to reset the rebuy column to "no" every week at Monday 1:00am.

I can do this manually logging into the mysql server

```
UPDATE users SET rebuy = 'no'
```

but I would prefer the server to do this just incase I'm not able to manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution would be to add a cron-job.
Here is a pretty nice tutorial for it 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

You can achieve exactly what you are looking for. Set the day and time and the cronjob
will do it automatically

It is hard to give you an code-example, since it may differ on different OS.

Your goal is to get something like:

connect to your server and type: `crontab -e`

`0 1 * * 1 /path/to/your/phpscript`
(not tested, but should be fine)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the server reset the flag.  Or, you can do basically nothing at all.  That is, instead of storing the flag value, you can store *when* the flag was last set.  Then, use a view to add the flag back in, based on this information.

So, define the table so you have:

```
rebuy_datetime date
```

Create a view:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*,
           (case when rebuy_datetime >= curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day + interval 1 hour 
                 then 'yes'
                 else 'no'
            end)
    from table t;
```

Then, when you query the table, the flag is set automagically.

Comment: I will test this out, never heard of view, new to this.